# Notepad++ underlining tags

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ seems to be underlining tags, both opening and closing, but i've only found one instance of it so far, anyone know what causes it?

[image: notepad++ hates me]

Comment: Are you sure this is not just the theme you are using...

Comment: I've been using this theme for about 4 months now, this is the first time it's happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem while using notepad++ in Windows 8. I found that in the settings hyperlinks were activated. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me... don't even know where is this option. But after I've specifically set the language for the file, it fixes the problem (Language > [yourfilelanguage])

Answer (score 28):

#### Current method

To disable link underlines in Notepad++:

- Go to **Settings** > **Preferences** > **Cloud & Link** > **Clickable Link Settings**
- Uncheck the "Enable" checkbox or check the "No underline" checkbox

[image]

#### Older method

In older versions of Notepad++, the way to disable link underlines was to:

- Go to **Settings** > **Preferences** > **MISC** > **Clickable Link Settings**
- Uncheck the "Enable" checkbox
- Restart Notepad++

[image]

Comment: Funny how my Notepad++ v7.8.8 (64 bit) w/build time of 2020-JUN-23 has the Preferences window from the 'Older method'

Answer (score 2):

Under Settings|Style Configurator you can set fonts including underlining for particular styles for specific languages.

You probably need to check language HTML and styles TAG and TAGEND. Uncheck the checkbox for underline.

Comment: This isn't a style issue, I've been using this style for a while.

Comment: @JamieTaylor - when I check the "underline" for those two styles, I get exactly the same underlining as your example.

Comment: Maybe, but this seems to be a n++ bug for me, "underline" is unchecked on all styles. Thanks though.

Comment: You could just hit the insert button on your keyboard and which should remove that little purple line "_"

Comment: @DoesEatOats that is just the cursor in "overwrite" mode, not an underlining of all html tags at the same time

Answer (score 2):

Whatever this was it was fixed with a restart, if it happens again I'll submit a bug report.

Thanks