# Notepad++ underlining matched tags/text instead of highlighting

Tags: settings, notepad++

I updated my notepad++ (the Je suis Charlie edition) and am having a problem highlighting matching text.

For some reason, instead of highlighting text, it underlines it like a link.  I followed the directions in the following discussion [Notepad++ underlining tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407964/notepad-underlining-tags). Under Settings>Preferences>Misc, i uncheck the 'enable' button for 'Clickable Link Settings' and restart Notepad++.

Funny thing is, this works for about a minute, and then it goes back to using underline styles instead of highlighting.  I can't figure out why it would be behaving this way. Have other had a similar problem, or found another solution?

David

Answer (score 0):

Unistalling and Reinstalling might solve your problem as hanging over a small issue might not worth it isnot it ???